# How to keep the current user intact while creating new user flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
    FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)).user;
    await Firestore.instance.collection("users").add({
      'uid': user.uid,
      'email': email,
      'name': name,
      'phone': number,
      'TodaySale': "0",
      'MonthlySale': "0",
      'Permission': permission
    });
    Firestore.instance.collection("employees").add({
      'Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Permission': permission,
      'Phone': number,
      'Email': email,
    });
```

I have already logged into the app and trying to create new employees whose data is stored in users collection and employee collection.
But after executing of the code the current user is changed to the added employee. How to createUser while keeping current user as same as it was logged on with.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#registration), the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method "is a two-step operation; it will first create the new account (if it does not already exist and the password is valid) and then automatically sign in the user in to that account". **There is no way to avoid the automatic sign in, with this method called from the frontend (i.e. from your Flutter app).**

You need to register these users through a backend process, for example via a Cloud Function.

The following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) explains how to build a module which allows end-users with a specific Admin role creating other users and assigning them other specific user roles. In a nutshell: From the frontend, the signed in user calls a Callable Cloud Function with the new user data. In the backend, the Cloud Function creates the user in the Auth service (and creates a user document in Firestore, exactly like you do with  `Firestore.instance.collection("employees").add()`). Therefore the current user in the frontend is not signed out.